# How to prevent fill value in textfield when it is already filled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried this solution, checking whether state variable is missing.

```
selectedOrganization?.barionId !== undefined
```

```js
<TextFieldItem
  primary="Barion ID"
  required="**"
  value={selectedOrganization?.barionId ?? ""}
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    selectedOrganization.barionId = event.target.value;
    setSelectedOrganization((preState) => ({
      ...preState,
      barionId: event.target.value,
    }));
  }}
  disabled={
    selectedOrganization?.barionId !== undefined
  }
/>
```

and has this state:

```js
const [selectedOrganization, setSelectedOrganization] = useState<
  OrganizationOut | undefined
>(undefined);
```

The challenge is that after the first character is filled into the textfield, the textfield gets disabled.

Comment: That is normal, since when you type something in the field you set the `barionId` so on the next render it will become disabled

Comment: How can you determine when the input is complete, unless you know for a fact that it must contain a given number of characters? And, event if the input must have a fixed length, how could you handle the need of re-editing it to fix a mistake, if you disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit complicated. You have a field that maybe filled (or not). If you want to disable any field that have a previous value, I prefer this trick that use when I have same problem.

**Define a variable for default value of the field**

```
let defaultValueFromSomewhereElse : String = "";
```

If the `defaultValueFromSomewhereElse` has a value (ex. from an api), assign it. then

**Define useState with default value**

```
const [selectedOrganization, setSelectedOrganization] = useState<OrganizationOut> 
(defaultValueFromSomewhereelse);
```

**Disable field base on `defaultValueFromSomewhereelse` length.**

```
<TextFieldItem
    primary="Barion ID"
    required="**"
    value={defaultValueFromSomewhereElse}
    onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        selectedOrganization.barionId = event.target.value;
        setSelectedOrganization((preState) => ({
        ...preState,
        barionId: event.target.value,
        }));
    }}
    disabled={
        defaultValueFromSomewhereElse.length > 0
    }
/>
```